# login fails on php app with internet explorer only

Tags: apache-2.2, php, internet-explorer

I have a php appl deployed on an apache2 server running on an older release of ubuntu.

I have 4 other servers running what *SHOULD* be an identical configuration (evidently isn't though).

The facts I have so far:

- I can login fine with firefox to this system and all others
- I can't login with internet explorer (It doesn't seem to set a PHPSESSID, and so takes me 
  back to the login screen)
- If I put the wrong password in, I get taken to the "wrong password" screen.

So it looks like the issue is that php is not starting the session for ie clients, any ideas for where to start looking?

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date on the server was incorrect, so the cookies were invalid as soon as they were sent.

Comment: How far was the skew? I'd be interested in knowing how much FF tolerated.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct. :)

Comment: It won't let me mark my answer as correct for 2 days :(

@benc: Skew was pretty decent, 33000 seconds if memory serves.

Answer (score 0):

check your settings for session into php.ini
if settings are saved server side on disk make sure
that the user that runs the web server process can
write into that location

Comment: If that were the case, it would not work in any browser.

Comment: did you look if cookies are enabled into ie ?